# Calculating the particular solution of the following nonhomogeneous system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matrix-exponential

The name of the game is systems of differential equations and matrix exponentials. I have the following problem: Apply the formula $\vec x(t) = e^{At} \vec c + e^{At} \int e^{At} \vec f(t) dt$ (where $A$ is the coefficient matrix) with $\vec c = 0$ to find a particular solution of the following nonhomogeneous system,

$$
      \vec x ^\prime = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} \vec x + 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        6\\
        12\\
        24\\
        \end{bmatrix}te^t
$$

I need to find $e^{At}$, which can be calculated by $e^{At} = P\Lambda_t P^{-1}$, where the column vectors of $P$ are the eigenvectors associated with each eigenvalue of $A$, and $\Lambda_t$ is the diagonal matrix with the diagonal entries of the form $e^{\lambda t}$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. E.g., 
$$
        \Lambda_t = \begin{bmatrix}
        e^{\lambda_1 t} & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & e^{\lambda_2 t} & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & e^{\lambda_3 t} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Upon calculating $\det (A - I \lambda)$, we find (unfortunately) that the characteristic equation of $A$ is $(1 - \lambda)^3$. So our only eigenvalue is $\lambda = 1$ with a multiplicity of three and a defect of two. For the sake of time and my job in the morning, I will cut to the chase:

**Question 1**: The only eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda = 1$ of multiplicity three. Would that mean 
$$
        \Lambda _t = \begin{bmatrix}
        e^t & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & e^t & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & e^t \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

**Question 2**: To accommodate the multiplicity three eigenvalue, we must form a three-chain $\{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ found by solving $(A - \lambda)^3 v_3 = 0, v_2 = (A - \lambda)v_3, v_1 = (A - \lambda)v_2$. I began with

$$
        v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
        1\\
        1\\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and end with

$$
        P = \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

**Is this value for $P$ correct?** Note that the three vectors imply that our solution is of the form

$$x_1 (t) = v_1 e^t$$
$$x_2 (t) = (v_1 t + v_2) e^t$$
$$x_3 (t) = (\frac{1}{2} v_1 t^2 + v_2 t + v_3) e^t$$

I tried using $v_1, v_1 t + v_2,$ and $\frac{1}{2} v_1 t^2 + v_2 t + v_3$ as my eigenvectors (and thus column vectors for $P$), but I came out to the same answer as below. Using my values of $P$ and $\Lambda _t$ in the formula stated in the problem, I do *not* get the right answer and instead get
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3t^2 e^t\\
        6t^2 e^t\\
        12t^2 e^t\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

whereas the correct answer is

$$
        e^t \begin{bmatrix}
        3t^2 + 2t^3 + t^4\\
        6t^2 + 4t^3\\
        12t^2\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You have a deficient matrix, so in this case, you need to find two generalized eigenvectors. This matrix is not digonalizable, you have a Jordan form. $P$ would be made up of the eigenvectors for the repeated eigenvalue and your $P$ is not correct. See example: http://www.math.utah.edu/~zwick/Classes/Fall2013_2280/Lectures/Lecture23_with_Examples.pdf

Comment: @Moo Should the columns of $P$ consist of those linearly independent eigenvectors of the form $v_1, v_1 t + v_2,$ etc? Your source is helpful, but it deals with homogeneous systems and does not mention matrix exponentials. I am familiar with how to accommodate deficient eigenvalues, but I am just confused with how we do that in this situation.

Comment: Do these help? http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/NonhomoSys.pdf

Comment: @Moo No, although the decoupling solution is interesting. I'm thinking about a method like this: http://www.math.rice.edu/~idu/Fall04/expmatrix.pdf, but I'm confused on how to apply it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve:

$$ x'(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix} x(t) + 
        \begin{pmatrix}
        6\\
        12\\
        24\\
        \end{pmatrix}te^t$$

**Method 1:** Decoupled $z$

Notice that the third equation is decoupled from the other two.

Based on this, we can easily solve using any of various methods:

$$z' = z + 24 t e^t \implies z(t) = e^t( c_3 + 12 t^2)$$

Substituting this into the second equation, we have:

$$y' = y + z + 12 t e^t = y + e^t( c_3 + 12 t^2) + 12 t e^t \implies y(t) = e^t( c_2 + c_3 t + (4 t + 6) t^2)$$

Repeating this process for the first equation yields:

$$x(t) = e^t \left( c_1 + c_2 t + \dfrac{1}{2} c_3 t^2 + (t^2 + 2 t + 3)t^2\right)$$

**Method 2:** Homogeneous and particular - we have the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

We have the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2,3} = 1$.

For the first eigenvalue, we solve $[A - I]v_1 = 0 \implies v_1 = (1, 0, 0)$

We cannot find two more linearly independent eigenvectors given this is a deficient matrix, so we find generalized ones.

For a second eigenvector, we will solve $[A - I]v_2 = v_1 \implies v_2 = (0, 1, 0)$.

For the third eigenvector, we will solve $[A - I]v_3 = v_2 \implies v_3 = (0, 0, 1)$.

These three eigenvectors make up your $P$.

For the homogeneous solution, we can now write:

$$x_h(t) = e^t \left(c_1 v_1 + c_2 (v_1 t + v_2) + c_3\left( \dfrac{1}{2} v_1  t^2 + v_2 t + v_3\right) \right)$$

Thus:

$$x_h(t) = e^t\left( c_1 \begin{pmatrix}  1\\ 0\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \left(\begin{pmatrix}  1\\ 0\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} t + \begin{pmatrix}  0\\ 1\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}\right) + c_3\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}  1\\ 0\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix}t^2 + \begin{pmatrix}  0\\ 1\\ 0\\ \end{pmatrix} t + \begin{pmatrix}  0\\ 0\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix}\right)  \right)$$

This is the method you refer to in your link.

Can you continue to find the particular solution, $x_p(t)$ from the link I provided (Method I gives a complete answer for comparison)?

**Update**

**Method 3:** Matrix Exponential (see [*Example 3*](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~xchen/teach/ode/NonhomoSys.pdf))

To be clear, from the work above, we have $\displaystyle e^{A t} = e^t \begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  t & \dfrac{t^2}{2} \\
 0 & 1 &  t \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

You want to follow example 3 in my link, where, for some initial condition $x(t_0)$ (which is not specified and can be any $t_0$), we would write the final solution as:

$$\displaystyle x(t) = e^{A(t-t_0)}x(t_0) +  \int_{t_0}^t e^{A(t-s)}~f(s)~ds,$$

where $f(s) = \begin{pmatrix}
        6\\
        12\\
        24\\
        \end{pmatrix}se^s$

It is also worth noting that there are many ways to solve such problems, these are only three examples (my link has two others), for example, see [*Nineteen Dubious Ways to Compute the Exponential of a Matrix, Twenty-Five Years Later*](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/19ways+.pdf)

Comment: Definitely. I'll post what I have in the morning. Thank you very much. Is my $\Lambda_t$ correct?

Comment: $P =\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, 
$J = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: And to conclude Method 2, we simply find a particular solution using $\vec x = \int_0^{t} e^{As} \vec f(s) ds$, and our general solution is given by $x(t) = x_p (t) + x_h (t)$?

Comment: And we want the values of $c_{1, 2, 3}$ to satisfy $x(0) = 0$?

Comment: Please see update.